# CSS right aligned list

Tags: html, css

How should I align the list to the right?
The text aligns perfectly, however **bullets do not**. Is there a simple and easy way to do so with CSS?

**Code:**

```
<ul style="text-align: right">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Even if I put the rules for LI elements directly to be aligned to the rigth, it does not work.

**EDIT**
I have attached an image showing what I want to achieve:
[image: On the right is what I want. On the left is what I have]

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/a2Jup/) it (view with FF)?

Comment: @Jon, no, please look at the image I have attached

Comment: similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977807/ul-li-bullets-as-image-an-right-side-next-to-the-text

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you need to align the bullets with the text you can use the `list-style-position` attribute, as follow:

```
.theList
{
    text-align: right;
    list-style-position: inside;
}​
```

Comment: .theList where is this class, with ul or li

Comment: in my case, i added html{direction:rtl;}

Comment: @wasim it's applied to UL. Rtl direction does something different (right aligned with bullet on right of text) because it's not intended for styling but for Rtl  layout languages. I'd avoid to use a style for its effect instead of its intent.

Comment: Little late to the game, but is it possible to align the bullets inside, and also aligned right.

Answer (score 20):

Use direction:

```
direction: rtl;
```

It is generally used for right to left languages.

edit:

Float each to the right and clear both.

```
float: right;
clear: both;
```

Comment: Thanks for response but it reverses bullets with text - this is not what I need.

Comment: Than please rephrase your question and add an image of desired output.  Because I clearly misunderstood.

Comment: Your suggestion with float: right kinda works, however with clear:both it breaks my design and the element is positioned outside the parent container

Comment: We will continue this when I get to a computer. I can't help you much more from mobile. @lukas

Comment: i prefere the direction solution ,  you saved my day (y)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, then just right-floating the li elements should suffice: http://jsfiddle.net/Jxzs4/1/

Answer (score -3):

```
<ul style="float:right; text-align:left; list-style:none;">
```

check this.....

if you want bullets then remove `list-style:none;`