# Text alignment in CSS

Tags: css

I am working on a project in which I want some text in un-ordered list in the right of the page like

This is demo text. o

But it is coming like

.This is demo text o

in the right side of page

where o is the bullet.

I have used direction: rtl; for this. I have tried float etc as well to achieve the required result but no success.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve the above result?

Comment: just float to the right `ul` and remove direction

Comment: can you post your code here?

Comment: It won't work unless you do some hacks, since this is the intended function of the `direction: rtl|ltr`. You could just skip the punctuation mark since you're working with a bulleted list.

Comment: @Morpheus he wants the bullet on the right side of the text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431037/css-right-aligned-list

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to be using `direction: rlt;` -- as I understand it, it's more intended for uses where the actual text direction is right-to-left.

A quick and easy way to achieve a similar effect would be to hide the normal bullets and replacing them through css, for example:

```
.list-right li {
  text-align: right;
  list-style: none;
}
.list-right li:after {
  content: ' \2022'; /* Bullet */
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
```

[JS Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/azuguf/2/edit)