# aligning bullet list to the right and bullets to the left of the text

Tags: html, css, bulletedlist

I was reading about `direction=rtl` but `rtl` puts the bullets on the right of the text. Is there a way to have the bullet list on the right side of a div with the bullets on the left of the text? Would I use the position attribute?

This is my `cshtml`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="instructions" id="instructions">
        <span style="font-weight:bold">Filter the results by selecting any number of the filter options: </span><br /><br />
        <div>
            <ol style="list-style-type:circle">
                <li>Check the checkbox and enter the desired search text </li>
                <li>Select multiple filters to expand your search</li>
                <li>Click the "Search" button to filter results</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
</div>
    <div class="filters">
        <div id="lblFilter">
            @Html.Label("Filter Options")
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="lblYears">
            <span style="margin-right:13px">@Html.Label("Begin")</span>
            <span style="margin-right:19px">@Html.Label("End")</span>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my `css`

```
div.instructions{
    float:right;
    width:75%;
    text-align:right;
}

div.filters{
    float:left;
}
```

This is what it currently looks like. I would like to get them over by the text
[image]

Comment: I believe your question has already been answered at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431037/css-right-aligned-list

Comment: @BrileyHooper Thank you. I couldn't find anything on it